# Why type of mongodb filter is not properly inferred by typescript?

Tags: typescript, mongodb

I have a base interface `Base` from which all my mognodb collections are extended. I'd like to create a common function `myTestFunction` that works on all my mongodb collections.

The below code shows the following error:

```js
import { type Collection } from "mongodb";

interface Base {
    id: string;
}

interface MyCollection extends Base {
    name: string;
}

async function myTestFunction<T extends Base>() {
    const mongoCollection: Collection<T> = {} as any; // for keeping this question succinct

    await mongoCollection.deleteOne({ id: "someId" });
    //                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ => Error
}

await myTestFunction<MyCollection>();
```

Error:

```
Argument of type '{ id: ""; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Filter<T>'.
  Type '{ id: ""; }' is not assignable to type '{ [Property in Join<WithId<T> extends string | number | boolean | RegExp | Date | Buffer | Uint8Array | ((...args: any[]) => any) | { _bsontype: string; } ? [] : WithId<...> extends readonly (infer ArrayType)[] ? [] | [...] : WithId<...> extends Map<...> ? [...] : WithId<...> extends object ? { [Key in "_id" | Extra...'.
    Type '{ id: ""; }' is not assignable to type '{ [Property in Join<WithId<T> extends string | number | boolean | RegExp | Date | Buffer | Uint8Array | ((...args: any[]) => any) | { _bsontype: string; } ? [] : WithId<...> extends readonly (infer ArrayType)[] ? [] | [...] : WithId<...> extends Map<...> ? [...] : WithId<...> extends object ? { [Key in "_id" | Extra...'.ts(2345)
```

[image]

I tried to understand what `Filter<T>` means. It shows autocompletion with `id` field.
[image]

But when I use it, typescript compains.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB default identifier is `_id`. Try with:

```
interface Base {
    _id: ObjectId;
}

async function myTestFunction<T extends Base>() {
    const mongoCollection: Collection<T> = {} as any; // for keeping this question succinct

    await mongoCollection.deleteOne({ _id: "someId" });
}
```